# php ecplise breakpoints don't stop

Tags: php, eclipse, joomla, xampp, xdebug

I am trying to use the debugger for my first time. On Windows 7, eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 1. I am trying to work with my localhost server. For that, I have installed XAMPP 1.8.0, and PHP 5.4.4.

I am following the example from

http://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_your_workstation_for_Joomla!_development

in particular, the 3rd step,"Configuring eclipse for joomla development" (that as you can see is a very detailed example).

So, I also have set the php lines

```
[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
```

and have set the port number accordingly in Windows->Preferences-> PHP -> Debug / Default Setting / PHP Debugger = XDebug, and configured the ports, 100000 for XDebug, and 10001 for the Zend Debugger, just like in the example.

Also have visited the http://xdebug.org/wizard.php and given the whole phpinfo() output. They suggested downloading php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll. Once done, put it in

```
C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll
```

and restarted apache from the XAMPP control panel V3.0.12. I did this right, since repeating the test at xdebug.org, it gives me now:

```
"You're already running the latest Xdebug version".
```

Therefore, the problem doesn't come this way.

After all, when I set a breakpoint in the second line of the file test.php, reading

```
"echo this is a test of XDebug"
```

the run goes to the end of execution showing the phpinfo() output. Also have checked the Windows -> Preferences -> PHP -> Debug / Break at first line.

Nothing, I have spent 3 days already in it!. Please, anybody can tell me why the debugger don't stop in any case (neither at the first line, nor at the breakpoint).

Any help will be deeply apreciated, PLEASE HELP. 
Thanks for your time.

carles

Comment: does phpinfo() show your xdebug to be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the breakpoints working with Eclipse and XDebug(Xamp server). Here are the detailed steps

http://programmersjunk.blogspot.com/2013/05/eclipse-and-xdebug.html

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem on a Windows system. Eclipse breakpoints work fine for any php command-line project and don't for any web application.
I have spent two hours to solve the problem.
Please check if your web server is listening on the 127.0.0.1 address and not on "localhost".
Why ? Because from Vista up, Windows uses ipv4 to connect to 127.0.0.1 while it uses ipv6 to connect lo the "localhost" address.

So, the solution is to use ipv4 on all the debug stack:

Launch the php built-in webserver (any or other) to listen on 127.0.0.1

php -S 127.0.0.1:80 c:\Users\Borgo\workspace

Furthermore consider adding this to your eclipse.ini:

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

I hope that this will help you

Regards from Italy

Comment: It is very unlikely that *exactly* the same answer will apply to 11 questions. If the questions are the same please flag them as duplicates. If they aren't the same then please tailor your answer to the specific circumstances of each one.

Comment: There are many similar questions, without any accepted answer. My advice could be a solution for some of them. It is hard to join the posts because the causes could be differents for the same problem as described by authors. How could i join questions ?

Comment: If the questions aren't duplicate then tailor your answer to each one. Simply pasting the same answer over and over again is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several issues that could be the root of this problem. In my case *Path Mapping* was the problem. To fix it, go to:

`Debug Configurations -> PHP Web Application -> Server -> Configure -> Path Mapping`

and select

*Do not map the following...*

because Eclipse can do this all by its self. So, removing the mapping made it work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how you start your debug session in Eclipse. So, lets start there:

There are two ways to start:

1. Using the menu `Run->Debug` option which Eclipse determines what is debugged/run or
2. the `Run->Debug Configurations...->Debug button` where you've specified the process

Usually with an application like Joomla! you need to specify a front-end debug configuration and separate back-end debug configuration (as they have different entry points).

For your test file you should be able to right click it and select the `Debug as...` option and have it stop at the first break point.

If you're doing all of this and it's still not working, then the first thing I would check is the `Run` menu and make sure the `Skip All Breakpoints` menu item is not checked.

After that check the `phpinfo()` results for an **`xdebug`** section (I realise you've indicated you've setup the `php.ini` with the xdebug parameters but it's worth checking).

If that fails search your `php.ini` and look for other `zend_extension` entries that may be conflicting...

Answer (score 0):

Check if your xdebug is working fine (php -i) following this instructions: https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

At Eclips, click Window > Show View > Breakpoints. Then click at "Add PHP Exception Breakpoint". Choose what you want.

Start debug.